# Firebase function how to search realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

[image]

I want to search firebase realtime database using firebase functions
Ex: in users I want to search if a particular email already exists.

Comment: Did you try anything yet? If not, this link probably has lots of good places to start: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+search+realtime+database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `orderByChild()` and `equalTo()` methods.

```js
async function doesEmailExist(email) {
  const snap = await admin.database().ref("users").orderByChild("email").equalTo(email).once("value")
  return !!snap.val()
  // snap.val() is null if absent
  // function returns false is email is absent
}
```